# BackgroundScheduler object has no attribute 'add_cron_job'

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

When I try to run my program I get "AttributeError: 'BackgroundScheduler' object has no attribute 'add_cron_job'"
When the program should correctly run.

Looking at the docs. It seems out of date. Its being ran on Linux.

```
import requests
import datetime
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# Provide the webhook URL that Discord generated
discord_webhook_url = 'super secrect URL'
Scheduler = Scheduler()
Scheduler.daemonic = False
Scheduler.start()
def job_function():
    # Get the BTC price from CoinDesk
    bitcoin_price_url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json'
    data = requests.get(bitcoin_price_url).json()
    price_in_usd = data['bpi']['USD']['rate']

    # Post the message to the Discord webhook
    data = {
        "content": "<@My Client ID> Bitcoin price is currently at $" + price_in_usd + " USD"
}
    requests.post(discord_webhook_url, data=data)

Scheduler.add_cron_job(job_function,  minute='0-59')
# the line above is where the error happenes.
```

It should just run. and complete the function of posting a message of the BTC price to discord.

Comment: You are importing `BackgroundScheduler` but then your code has `Scheduler = Scheduler()`. Where does `Scheduler` come from? (also, don't name objects the same as classes, you are hiding the class by doing this).

Comment: What exactly do you suppose is out of date? No scheduler class has a method called "add_cron_job()".